# How can I make the project dropdowns in the portfolio section of my website load faster?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My [website](https://www.pravdew.com/) loads just fine, but when I attempt opening any of the projects in my portfolio section, it takes maybe a second too long to load - desktop & mobile.

**Here's a snippet of code that I think may be causing this** - I'm not sure what changes to make to fix it, please help.

Thank you

```
`jQuery('.portfolio-item a').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $that = jQuery(this);
            var $item = $that.closest(".portfolio-item");
            
            if ($item.find('.loading').length===0) {
                jQuery('<div />').addClass('loading').appendTo($item);
                $that.parent().addClass('active');

                var $loading = $item.find('.loading'),
                    $container = jQuery('#portfolio-details'),
                    timer = 1;
                
                if ($container.is(':visible')) {
                    closeProject();
                    timer = 800;
                    $loading.animate({width:'70%'}, {duration:2000, queue:false});
                }

                setTimeout(function() {

                    $loading.stop(true, false).animate({width:'70%'},   
{duration:5000, queue:false});
                    
                    //Add AJAX query to the url
                    var url = $that.attr("href")+"?ajax=1";
                    
                    jQuery.get(url).done(function(response) {
                        $container.html(response);
                        
                        $container.waitForImages(function() {
                            $loading.stop(true, false).animate({width:'100%'}, 
{duration:500, queue:true});
                            
                            $loading.animate({opacity:0}, {duration:100, 
queue:true, complete:function() {
                                $that.parent().removeClass('active');
                                jQuery(this).remove();

                                $container.show().css({opacity:0}); 
                                
                                that.imageSlider($container, function() {
                                    jQuery(document).scrollTo($container, 600, 
{offset:{top:-parseInt(jQuery(".navbar").height(), 10), left:0}});
                                    $container.animate({opacity:1}, {duration:600, 
queue:false});
                                    $container.attr('data-current', 
$that.data("rel"));
                                });
                            }});
                        });`
```

Comment: In general, your script is waiting for the ajax, (the one I tested took 1.23 seconds to load), then waiting for the images to fully load before scrolling to the target. Not a good user experience. Retool it so it scrolls to the screen first and then shows things loading. That way the user knows what is happening. The way it is now, it appears to be non-responsive (temporarily)

Comment: Thank you, any idea what the code for that would look like?